# Death Note no Python: Problemas em dois elif's no código

Tags: python

No meu código do Death Note em Python há **duas condições (elifs) que não funcionam:**

**1ª condição (penúltima): Deve mostrar a condição que a vítima é desconhecida e precisa digitar o nome dela.**

**2ª condição (última): Vítimas que foram digitadas anteriormente no loop sentinela sejam mostradas que já estão mortas e que é preciso digitar o nome de uma outra vítima.**

Código abaixo:

```
usuario = ""
while usuario == "":
    print ("LEMBRETE: Para usar o caderno é obrigatório inserir o nome")
    usuario = str (input("Digite o nome do usuário do caderno: "))    
print ("Bem vindo ao Death Note {}".format(usuario))
print ("Deseja matar alguém? ")
resposta = str (input("S - Sim | N - Não: "))[0]
while resposta == 'S' or resposta == 's': 
    nome = str (input("Digite o nome da ví­tima: "))
    morte = str (input("Digite a causa da morte: "))
    if morte == "" and nome != usuario:
        print ("O nome da vítima é {}".format(nome))
        print ("Causa da morte: Parada cardí­aca")
    elif nome != usuario: 
        print ("O nome da vítima é {}".format(nome))
        print ("Causa da morte: {}".format(morte))
    elif morte == "" and nome == usuario:
        print ("{} você digitou seu próprio nome no Death Note".format(nome))
        print ("Causa de sua morte: Parada cardí­aca")
        print ("Você não pode mais usar o Death Note")
        break
    elif nome == usuario:
        print ("{} você digitou seu próprio nome no Death Note!".format(nome))
        print ("Causa de sua morte: {}".format(morte))
        print ("Você não pode mais usar o Death Note")
        break
    elif nome == "": # Condição que não executa
        print ("É preciso digitar o nome de sua vítima")
    elif nome == nome: # Condição que não executa
        print ("Você já inseriu o nome dessa pessoa!")
        print ("Por favor, digite outro nome")

    print ("Deseja matar mais alguém {}?".format(usuario))
    resposta = str (input("S - Sim | N - Não: "))[0]

if resposta == 'N' or resposta == 'n':
    print ("{} volte quando quiser para limpar o mundo!!!".format(usuario))
```

Comment: O que você considera uma vítima desconhecida? Um nome que não está numa lista de vítimas, por exemplo? Ou algo que não faz sentido como nome de uma vítima (caracteres que não sejam letras, por exemplo)?

Comment: Caso o nome da vítima seja vazio ele tem que cair no `elif nome == ""` enquanto que o nome repetido da vítima anterior caia no `elif nome == nome` (esse if acho que está errado)

Comment: O que você está afim é de um código pronto, sem explicação nem nada, mas que apenas funcione? Ou seja, você está querendo que a gente faça sua atividade?

Comment: Cara na boa é eu não consigo fazer com que as duas últimas condições `elif` funcionem por que esse código não cai nessa condições, aliás **esse código não é nenhuma atividade que vale ponto e só para treinar no Python**.

Comment: @Breno desculpe a grosseria, mas o que digo é verdade isso ai pra mim é divertimento misturado com estudo, além disso alterei a descrição espero que consiga entender a explicação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie uma lista para armazenar os nomes inseridos e cheque se se há alguma repetição.

```
nomes = ['']
```

Você vai precisar alterar as seguintes condições:

```
if morte == "" and nome != usuario and nome not in nomes:
...

elif nome != usuario and nome not in nomes:
...

elif nome in nomes: # Precisa cair nessa condição caso a vítima for repetida
```

Insira o `nome` digitado na lista `nomes` no fim do laço while:

```
nomes.append(nome)
```

Você também pode inserir o nome do usuário na lista de nomes antes de entrar no laço principal e simplificar as condições:

```
nomes.append(usuario)
...

if morte == "" and nome not in nomes:
...

elif nome not in nomes:
...
```

Outra coisa: você não precisa transformar um input para string, pois a função [input() já retorna uma string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

```
>>> str (input("S - Sim | N - Não: "))[0] == (input("S - Sim | N - Não: "))[0]
S - Sim | N - Não: s
S - Sim | N - Não: s
True
```

....

```
usuario = ""
nomes = ['']
while usuario == "":
    print ("LEMBRETE: Para usar o caderno é obrigatório inserir o nome")
    usuario = input("Digite o nome do usuário do caderno: ")

nomes.append(usuario)

print (f"Bem vindo ao Death Note, {usuario}")
print ("Deseja matar alguém? ")

resposta = input("S - Sim | N - Não: ")[0]

while resposta == 'S' or resposta == 's':

    nome = input("Digite o nome da vítima: ")
    morte = input("Digite a causa da morte: ")

    if morte == "" and nome not in nomes:
        print (f"O nome da vítima é {nome}")
        print ("Causa da morte: Parada cardíaca")

    elif nome != usuario and nome not in nomes:
        print (f"O nome da vítima é {nome}")
        print (f"Causa da morte: {morte}")

    elif morte == "" and nome == usuario:
        print (f"{nome}, você digitou seu próprio nome no Death Note")
        print ("Causa de sua morte: Parada cardíaca")
        print ("Você não pode mais usar o Death Note")
        break

    elif nome == usuario:
        print (f"{nome}, você digitou seu próprio nome no Death Note!")
        print (f"Causa de sua morte: {morte}")
        print ("Você não pode mais usar o Death Note")
        break

    elif nome == "": # Precisa cair nessa condição caso a vítima for desconhecida
        print ("É preciso digitar o nome de sua vítima")

    elif nome in nomes: # Precisa cair nessa condição caso a vítima for repetida
        print ("Você já inseriu o nome dessa pessoa!")
        print ("Por favor, digite outro nome")

    nomes.append(nome)
    print (f"Deseja matar mais alguém, {usuario}?")
    resposta = input("S - Sim | N - Não: ")[0]

if resposta == 'N' or resposta == 'n':
    print (f"{usuario}, volte quando quiser para limpar o mundo!!!")
```

Comment: Não tem como mostrar essas mudanças no meu código porque não está saindo muito bem o resultado apenas mostrando em partes

Comment: 1) Insira nomes = [] no topo do código;

2) altere as condições; 

3) insira nomes.append(nome) no fim do laço while principal (em cima de print("Deseja matar mais alguém, {}?".format(usuario))).

Comment: Não consigo fazer com que funcione

Comment: Se a resposta lhe ajudou, aceite-a

Comment: Os dois últimos `elifs` não funcionam

Comment: Funciona sim, você está fazendo alguma coisa errada. Tente copiar e colar o código inteiro. E aceita a pergunta!

Comment: Murilo me desculpe, agora eu percebi o que estava dando de errado no código eu tinha feito `nomes = []` ao invés de `nomes = ['']` só depois de muito tempo percebi o que estava dando de errado, mas o código realmente funciona nas dois últimos `elifs`.

Comment: Obrigado, depois lhe recompensarei com os pontos ofertados quando o sistema me disponibilizar essa ação.

Comment: @AlexF. basta você dar o aceite na resposta...

Comment: Já aceitei, você não recebeu os 50 pontos de recompensa?!

Comment: @AlexF. Na verdade também existe a opção de aceitar uma resposta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052 - não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquela resposta resolveu o problema. E na verdade, esse é o jeito "padrão" de indicar que a resposta resolveu o problema. Recompensas são uma forma de "bônus", que também são válidos, claro, mas aceitar respostas é o mais usual

Comment: @MuriloSitonio vê ai se eu aceitei a sua resposta, acho que agora foi